# mod_secdownload for Apache 2.x

Tags: apache-2.2, hotlinking

Is there something like [mod_secdownload](http://lighttpd.net/documentation/secdownload.html) (which is available for lighttpd) also available for Apache 2.x?

The mod provides expiring URLs, so that it is possible to prevent hotlinking of files. A similar feature is used by Amazon S3.

The server application has to generate a hash with a secret code and an expiry timestamp so that URLs only live for a given duration of time.

The closest thing I could find is [mod_auth_token](http://www.synd.info/downloads/releases/), but that seems to be Apache 1.3 only.

---

Additional Hints:

- As suggested by HD: [mod_auth_token](http://www.synd.info/downloads/releases/) works great with Apache 2.x
- If you need some hints on how to use it: Info Page at [nixbit.com](http://nixbit.com/cat/internet/nttp-%28www%29/mod-auth-token/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that mod_auth_token doesn't work with Apache2? I compiled the module with apache2-devel and also I see some apache2-mod_auth_token rpm packages in rpm.pbone.net

Comment: Seems to actually work. Thought it was only Apache 1.x because I can't find absolutely NO documentation about it. Any hints? How do I use it?

Comment: Great! It works! *jump* *happy*