# How to enable hotlink protection without hardcoding my domain in the Apache config file?

Tags: apache-2.2, hotlinking

Been surfing around for a solution for a couple days now.

How do I enable Apache hotlink protection without hardcoding my domain in the config file so I can port the code to my other domains without having to update the config file every time?

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.(com|net|org) [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|png)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

... And this is what Apache suggests:

```
SetEnvIf Referer example\.com localreferer
<FilesMatch \.(jpg|png|gif)$>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=localreferer
</FilesMatch>
```

... both of which hardcode the domain in their rules.

The closest I came to finding any info that covers this is [right here on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/300089/), but the conclusion was that it cannot be done. Based on my research, that appears to be true, but I didn't find any questions or commentary dedicated soley to this question.

If anyone's curious, [here is the link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/access.html#blocked-inline-images) to the Apache 2 docs that cover this topic.

Note that Apache environment variables (e.g. `%{HTTP_REFERER}`) **cannot** be used in the `RewriteCond`'s *CondPattern* argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>What about checking to see if Host matches the Referrer? E.g.</strike>

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !%{HTTP_HOST}
```

**Edit**

This won't work, as stated by the OP. For Apache 2.4 you can use:

```
RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch '*://%{HTTP_HOST}/*'"
```

For 2.2, you could write a small handler in mod_perl or mod_python that could perform the compare and issue the 403 error.

To achieve this with mod_python:

Create a file in your docroot (in my case /var/www/) called `hotlink.py`

```
from mod_python import apache

def headerparserhandler(req):
    if req.headers_in.get("Host") != req.headers_in.get("Referer"):
            return apache.HTTP_FORBIDDEN
    return apache.OK
```

In you Apache config:

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
   ...
   AddHandler mod_python .jpg
   AddHandler mod_python .gif
   PythonHeaderParserHandler /var/www/hotlink.py
   #PythonDebug On
 </Directory>
```

Now all requests for .jpg and .gif will be first checked by hotlink.py. With mod_python you can also check against the `req.server.server_hostname` attribute to check against `ServerName` instead of the incoming Host header.

Comment: Seems like it should work, right? Unfortunately, as the last sentence of my question points out, you can't use environment variables in the `RewriteCond`'s *CondPattern*.

Comment: @Jeff Doh, I should have checked. I've just seen in Apache 2.4 redirect docs suggest something. I'll update my answer and think about 2.2.

Comment: It seems to me that unless there is a way to compare `%{HTTP_REFERER}` with `%{HTTP_HOST}% on the `RewriteCond`'s *TestString* and then compare it to "something" (maybe even nothing!) on the same *CondPattern*, this simply can't be done with Ap2.2.

Comment: @Jeff I should have read your post more carefully as you clearly stated that RewriteCond can't compare HTTP headers. The only way I can think to achieve this is by writing a handler in mod_python or mod_perl.

Comment: Truly appreciate your effort. +1 and checkmark.